# Display custom pop over on standard field in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, popover

I wanted to show a custom pop over on a standard field in lightning. I know pop overs can be display using the overlay library. However, I am not sure how can i achieve this on a standard field.

It would be even better if it's possible to show it on a highlight panel.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Including your code will help others provide feedback bas d on your specific use case, otherwise, the question might be too broad

Comment: @glls, I have used the pop over styles from the lightning design system and i have a button on the click of which i show the pop over. But as i said, i wanted to achieve this on a standard field of the highlight panel. So, i do not know a way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really customize the standard Lightning UI. Instead, you'd have to write a custom component mimicking the [standard record header](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/) (choose the "record home" variant), and then you could customize it to include your custom popover. You'd also have to use a custom Lightning Page to show this component. Overall, it's not impossible, but may be quite a bit of work for such a small result.